# What is the simplest way to create a page tab on the latest version of fb?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, iframe, tabs

All I want to do is create a few pages with sign up forms for our fans and customers on our business facebook page.

I created the new app, named it and went on to the basic settings. From what I can tell I just need to set up the "page tab" info. I Named the tab, put in the page tab url, secure page tab url and uploaded a tab image.

Then I wait for it to show up on our fb page. I refresh the page and for a few seconds it looks like something is being loaded in the list of tabs. But then it stops and the layout of default tabs (photos, likes, and events) are unchanged.

The tab should link to the app url which should load inside of an iframe which will have the html from our web server.

That's how I understand it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You must add manually the application on your page through this URL: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/

Remember to replace APP_ID first.

Comment: nothing too complicated

https://www.kvsupply.com/webpilot/html/kv-supply-email-signup.html

Comment: The form doesn't show up, and If understand correctly, you already completed URL inputs through your application for the " Page Tab "? Interesting, it should work. Is it possible to have the page's link?

Comment: https://www.kvsupply.com/webpilot/html/kv-supply-email-signup.html

yes, this is the url I put in the app basic set up. "Page tab url" and "Secure Page Tab URL" is what the fb dev is asking for.

Comment: I meant the Facebook page, not the form ;)

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/pages/KV-Supply/109203575775620?id=109203575775620&sk=app_157723177723454

Comment: Interesting, have you switched off the sandbox mode in your app?